# VS2017 Publish to Azure does not See VM

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I recently wrote a .NET core web service, and not I'm attempting to publish it up to an Azure VM (the VM is Server2016 if it makes any difference).  I did NOT setup the VM (My Azure admin did).  I CAN connect to the SQL server on the VM (admin had to open some ports)

I'm 
1)Right click Publish
2)Select Existing
3)Select "Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines"
4)Click Publish

The issue is that I don't SEE my virtual machine to select it after step 4

Help?

Comment: do you have enough rights to Azure?

Comment: How about asking your admin? It's his job to make sure he gave you enough rights and permissions

Comment: Brand new Admin - company is totally new to Azure